# Address already in use when launching nodeos

Tags: nodeos

When starting my local nodeos instance...

```
$ nodeos
```

I get the following error message...

```
1533876ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:323           plugin_startup       ] start listening for http requests
1533877ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:330           plugin_startup       ] http service failed to start: Address already in use
1533878ms thread-0   main.cpp:133                  main                 ] Address already in use
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the port required by nodeos, port 8888 by default, is already being used by another running process. It's likely that you're running a keosd process, from starting a previous instance of nodeos. If you're on a Mac, you can find existing keosd processes using...

```
$ ps -ax | grep keosd
```

And then kill any running keosd processes using...

```
$ kill -9
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just change the port and run `$ nodeos --http-server-address=127.0.0.1:9989` if you want multiple `nodeos` instances.  `--p2p-listen-endpoint=localhost:9998` should also be running on a unique port.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably already running another nodeos, you can do a `killall nodeos` and try again.

It could also be that you have a different process running on default port 8888, in that canse you can access your config.ini file and change the port.